# How to send a POST request with the Javascript Soup library?

Tags: javascript, gnome

I'm trying to write a Gnome program in Javascript. HTTP requests are done with a library called Soup, and GET requests start with something like:

```
msg = Soup.Message.new('GET', self.url) ...
```

Examples for GET requests are all over the net, but how to do a POST request?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on our [chat conversation](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/46393), this code will work:

```
msg = Soup.Message.new('POST', self.url);
var POSTparams = 'try=this';
msg.set_request ('application/x-www-form-urlencoded', 2, POSTparams, POSTparams.length);
```

The syntax seems to be:

```
msg.set_request('MIME type', (2), 'params=here', 'params=here'.length);
```

This answer was also based on the following:

- [How to format the request body and its MIME type](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14551194/1256925)
- [libsoup POST requests in `C`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10178750/http-post-with-libsoup) for the syntax of this function

Comment: I should have seen that answer coming. :) The question is: Where to put the data?

Comment: @lyle could you link me to the library's page please?

Comment: Good thinking. :) Never occured to me they should have their own documentation somewhere: https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/libsoup

Comment: It's a C library, so they have C examples. Still need to figure out how the JS bindings look like.

Comment: @lyle I've posted what I'd say it might be. I'm not at all sure about it though.

Comment: Nope, both don't work. There's no function called .body(), and adding the parameters to the url makes them GET parameters.

Comment: @lyle how about this? By the way, do you have any live examples where I can test for myself?

Comment: "Soup.Message.set_request (msg, 'try=this')" seems to be going somewhere, but it says the method expects 4 arguments.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46393/discussion-between-joeytje50-and-lyle)

Comment: Too many arguments to method Soup.Message.set_request: expected 3, got 4